# Two way communication between asp.net app and desktop app using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, desktop-application

Is it possible to have this type of communication using signalR: The two applications are not on the same machine I want the ASP.NET application sends some data to Windows application, Windows application makes some processing then sends data back to ASP.NET application. 
If yes, do i need to host signalr server in a separate application or can i host it in the ASP.NET application any examples how to acheive this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of documentation and samples available on github. Have you checked any of this out yet? https://github.com/SignalR/Samples https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SignalR server will allow the two applications to communicate with each other. The SignalR server would be a different application though it can run on the same machine as your ASP.Net app.